# Why is my <app-globals>'s port to Polymer 1.0 on working in Chrome and not on Firefox/Safari?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've been trying to port the `<app-globals>` element behavior, to share variables between elements, as [illustrated in the Polymer 0.5 Developer Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global), to Polymer 1.0.

I've got to an element that is full working on Chrome and Chrome for Android, but doesn't seem to work on Safari, Firefox or Chrome for iOS. You can check [the live jsbin](http://jsbin.com/takike/edit?html,output). Just open it on Chrome to see it working.

Why doesn't it work on Safari/Firefox?
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several issues that stopped your example from working. I have a working copy of your code in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rib2B87Lyc74EwEL7yOK?p=preview) (I had some issues with JS Bin, that's why I moved to Plunker).

Make sure you link the to the scripts correctly (you had `href` instead of `src`).

```
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to create Polymer elements in your main documents, listen to the `HTMLImports.whenReady` event ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html)). This is probably the main reason for problems in Firefox.

```
HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
    Polymer({
```

When you register the element, you need to specify the id again using `is`.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'demo-test',
    populate: function() {
```

Comment: Yeah I was missing the HTMLImports.whenReady part. Thank you for the detailed answer!